How to convert 3D image tensor into PyTorch MNIST format for inference?
I have trained the following model with the Pytorch MNIST dataset and saved it in the end.
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim


train_data = datasets.MNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    transform=ToTensor(),
    download=True
    )

test_data = datasets.MNIST(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    transform=ToTensor(),
    download=True
    )


loaders = {
    "train": DataLoader(train_data,
                        batch_size=100,
                        shuffle=True,
                        num_workers=0),

    "test": DataLoader(test_data,
                    batch_size=100,
                    shuffle=True,
                    num_workers=0)
}

class CNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return F.softmax(x)
    

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

model = CNN().to(device)

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),
                    lr=0.001)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()


def train(epoch):

    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(loaders["train"]):
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = loss_fn(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % 20 == 0:
            print(f'Train epoch: {epoch} [{batch_idx * len(data)}/{len(loaders["train"].dataset)} ({100. * batch_idx / len(loaders["train"]):.0f}%)]\t{loss.item():.6f}')


def test():
    model.eval()

    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in loaders["test"]:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += loss_fn(output, target).item()
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

    test_loss /= len(loaders['test'].dataset)
    print(f'\nTest set: Average loss: {test_loss:.4f}, Accuracy: {correct}/{len(loaders["test"].dataset)} ({100. * correct / len(loaders["test"].dataset):.0f}%\n)')


for epoch in range(1, 11):
    train(epoch)
    test()

torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model.pth")

Now I want to do inferences on some images that are not part of the MNIST dataset. The images are jpg's and are loaded with OpenCV as (28, 28) NumPy arrays (see inline-comments for types and shapes):
import cv2
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.transforms import Compose, ToTensor


# same class as in the file above
class CNN(nn.Module):

        def __init__(self):
            super(CNN, self).__init__()

            self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
            self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)

        def forward(self, x):
            x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
            x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
            x = x.view(-1, 320)
            x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
            x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
            x = self.fc2(x)

            return F.softmax(x)

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

model = CNN().to(device)

model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.pth"))


img = cv2.imread("image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

print(type(img))  # Output: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(img.shape)  # Output: (28, 28)

model.eval()

with torch.no_grad():

    transform = Compose([ToTensor()])
    img = transform(img)

    print(type(img))  # Output: <class 'torch.Tensor'>
    print(img.shape)  # Output: torch.Size([1, 28, 28])

    output = model(img)
    pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
    print(pred)

When doing inference, the model always predicts "3" for any test sample, and I get the following warning:
UserWarning: dropout2d: Received a 3D input to dropout2d and assuming that channel-wise 1D dropout behavior is desired - input is interpreted as shape (N, C, L), where C is the channel dim. This behavior will change in a future release to interpret the input as one without a batch dimension, i.e., shape (C, H, W). To maintain the 1D channel-wise dropout behavior, please switch to using dropout1d instead.
  warnings.warn("dropout2d: Received a 3D input to dropout2d and assuming that channel-wise "
c:/Users/u/project/venv/src/digits_model_prediction.py:28: UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument.
  return F.softmax(x)

It seems that I have not formatted my images for inference in the correct way. I tried to access the images in the dataloader of the training file, but I ended up with a DataLoader object, unable to access the shapes of the images. Can you tell me how I need to format my images for inference?
UPDATE:
Running
print(train_data.data[0].shape)
print(type(train_data.data[0]))

in the training file yields
torch.Size([28, 28])
<class 'torch.Tensor'>

This should mean that the individual images in the dataloader are tensors of size 28x28.
However, converting the NumPy image array in the inference file into a 28x28 tensor via
transform = Compose([ToTensor()])
img = transform(img)
img = img.view(28, 28)
print(type(img))  # Output: <class 'torch.Tensor'>
print(img.shape)  # Output: torch.Size([28, 28])

results in the following error, when running the entire inference file:
RuntimeError: Expected 3D (unbatched) or 4D (batched) input to conv2d, but got input of size: [28, 28]

Now I am fully confused since I gave the model the exact shape and type of data, but it is still not enough.
